# Consulta access keysensitive

Tags: sql, ms-access

Tengo una consulta del estilo:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE keyTabla = 'cadena';
```

Lo que quiero es que esta consulta compare la  key y la cadena pero discriminando mayúsculas de minúsculas.

Comment: a que te refieres con discriminar? sin respetar las mayusculas de las minuscula o por el contrario?

Comment: @JackNavaRow imagino que querrá algo del estilo `equalsIgnoreCase()` de java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es que te compare las cadenas exactamente, teniendo en cuenta mayúsculas y minúsculas, la función es `StrComp()`.

Se usa de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE StrComp(keytabla, "cadena", 0) = 0;
```

La función tiene la siguiente sintaxis:

```
StrComp(string1, string2, modoComparacion)
```

**string1** y **string 2** son las cadenas a comparar.

**modoComparacion** es cómo se comparan las cadenas, pudiendo ser '*Binario*' (valor 0) que distingue las mayúsculas de minúsculas y '*Texto*' (valor 1) que no distingue mayúsculas de minúsculas.

La función devuelve **0** si las cadenas son iguales. Si no lo son, devuelve **1** o **-1**.

Espero que esta función te resuelva el problema.

Answer (score 1):

Buenas! Creo que lo que estás buscando es lo siguiente, comparar siempre en mayusculas o minusculas:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE UCase(keyTabla) = UCase('cadena');
```

En este caso te compararía el campo de la tabla en mayúsculas con el dato de la cadena también en mayúsculas

Comment: la cosa es que keyTabla esta en mayuusculas y cadena en minusculas y aun asi me traga la consulta y me devuelve 2 registros (uno mayus y otro minus) con el mismo valor porque detecta el valor de la cadena pero no el case, y necesito que sea case sensitive. Gracias por responder :)